# Unique product name for Sentinel-2 products, which does not change after re-processing by the distributor

Tags: sentinel-2, satellite

Currently, I use the names of the Sentinel-2 space imagery product archives as a unique image identifier in the database.

It turns out that this identifier contains **processing data and time**, which changes when the data is re-processed, such as when the Processing baseline is changed. See [Sentinel-2 Naming Convention](https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/naming-convention). Example:
S2B_MSIL1C_20220518T073609_N0400_R092_T40VFQ_**20220518T080412**

This circumstance leads to loss of links in the database tables when re-downloading the space imagery after it has been updated on the distributor's website.

I am looking for a **unique product name** for Sentinel-2 space imagery **that does not change** when re-processing the raw data (e.g., due to changes in the standard processing baseline).

Comment: How about the granule name